# I can't install SQL Server 2012 on Windows 8

Tags: sql, windows-8, sql-server-2012

When I try to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows 8, I have a problem.

Windows installer error message:

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'microsoft.vc80.atl,version="8.0.50727.6229",publickeytoken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorarchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to help and support for more information. hresult: 0x80070422.

Comment: What kind of processor does your computer have? 32bit, 64bit? and what kind of SQL Server 2012 are you downloading (32 or 64 bit)?

Comment: I download 64 bit for my laptop

Comment: my laptop using 64 bit , so I download it , is that wrong ? can you have a link down for 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a 64bit SQL Server 2012, with a 32bit processor. I would suggest to download and install the 32bit version.

Answer (score 0):

Download sql server on the basis of the processor of your computer/laptop.(32bit/64bit/ for mac version). you would not face this error